# Merge Columns without deleting or affecting the rows

Tags: google-sheets, merge

Im seeking some experienced advice, as I have been working on a little project to automate how we gather data in my office using Google Sheets(Please note that I can't use add-ons).
I'm encountering difficulties in finding a way to merge columns that have the same name, but without deleting/merging the row(because im pulling stats for the different tasks employees handle).

In the example you can see that column A has names that repeat because each individual completes one or more tasks, so my goal would be to find a way to automatically merge the repeating names in column A without affecting the rest of the columns.

I believe it is important to know that the table auto-populates as im currently using a filter function, because I paste all my data in the excel and it filters only my agents names.

Here is the formula that im using in c26:

```
=FILTER(A3:G22,ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A3:A22,{"Mary";"Jason";"Ana";"Jen";"Ben";"Helen";"Dan";"Richard";"Breg"},0))))
```

Please tell me that there is a way to do this!

Here is a link to the example Doc That I made
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsCeHfzzbRsUDnj6UmmCdfzjryp-2xW09UTCx_qfIpA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can do it, but can't merge by formula:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA ( 
    ifna ( 
      vlookup (
        ifna ( 
          sort (
            { row(A4:A22) * 
              len ( vlookup ( A4:A22,
                  {"Ana";"Jen";"Ben";"Helen";"Dan";"Richard";"Breg"},1,0)
              )^0}
            ,1,true
          ),""
        )
        , { row(A4:A22), 
            left(A4:A22, 1000 * 
                transpose (
                   split (join("","1," & rept("0,",countif(A4:A22,unique(A4:A22))-1)),",",true,true))
                ),
            B4:G22
          },{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},false
      ),""
    )
  )
```

[image]

Another formula with the same result:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA ( 
     ifna(vlookup (
          sort (
            { row(A4:A22) * 
              len ( vlookup ( A4:A22,
                  {"Ana";"Jen";"Ben";"Helen";"Dan";"Richard";"Breg"},1,0)
              )^0}
            ,1,true
          ), 
          { row(A4:A22),
            if(transpose(split(join(
               "","1," & rept("0,",COUNTIF(A4:A22,unique(A4:A22))-1)),",",true,true))=1,
               A4:A22,""
            ),B4:G22
          },{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},false),""
     )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of discussion on the sheet, this query() will display only one name per agent, but still list all the rows for that agent.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:G22,IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A22,Sheet1!A1:A22,ROW(Sheet1!A1:A22),"<="&ROW(Sheet1!A1:A22))>1,"",Sheet1!A1:A22)},"select Col8,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col1 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A2:A)&"' order by Col1 label Col8'Name'",3),9^99,7))
```